# Google Sheet: Script - Copy/Paste, Time delay, Copy/Paste, repeat for all values in column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am trying to build a spreadsheet that automatically calculates intrinsic value of a list of stocks.

Cell 3 and cell 4 are linked to another sheet which has a range of formulas including data drawn from external websites.

I would like to write a script for a custom function that will use this setup:

1. Entered into cell 2, with cell 1 as an argument
2. Copies the ticker value (cell 1) into cell 3, activating the other sheet functions to do their calculations
3. After some time (e.g. 30 seconds), reads the value in cell 4 from those other functions
4. Returns the final value into cell 2.

[image: Spreadsheet Capture]

I would then use this function for all values in column A.
So far Ive been able to figure out how to copy and paste one value. Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
function val(ticker) { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   //access to the spreadsheet
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('List of Companies')); //access to the sheet by name
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2'); //assign the range you want to copy
  var copy = range.getValues();
  sheet.getRange('D2').setValue(copy) //new range you want to paste a value
}
```

Comment: If you want a custom function for this, make sure it accepts a range array argument (rather than a single cell), and also configure it to do the lookup task as well, because it cannot modify cells as an intermediate step in its execution - only the values of the cells in its return range are modifiable. You'll want to batch construct your lookup requests as well - see documentation for `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll`. my recommendation is to not use a custom function, but rather a normal script.

Comment: Thank you tehhowch. Will look into this further using your recommendations. May be back from more help soon :) Edit. Also realised that i will have a list of more than 2000 companies... could take a while.